# Energy stored in electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy, integration, singularities

I know that energy stored in electric field / unit volume = $\frac{1}{2} \epsilon\,E^2$.

so can I say that for any configuration calculating $\int \frac{1}{2} \epsilon\, E^2 \,d^3r$ over whole space - gives me the potential energy stored stored in the system

for instance
for $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ ....separated by distance $d$,

$\int \frac{1}{2} \epsilon\, E^2 \,d^3r$ over whole space $= \frac{KQ_1Q_2}{d} $?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78112/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The identity $\int \frac{1}{2} \epsilon\, E^2 \,d^3r$ over whole space $= \frac{KQ_1Q_2}{d} $ is evidently untenable as the right-hand side may have negative sign whereas the left-hand side is always positive.

Answer (score 1):

You will get infinity because in addition to $kQ_1Q_2/d$, it also includes the self-energy of the two point charges, which is infinity.

Comment: Care to expand. How infinity came here?

Comment: Close to a charge, $E \sim 1/r^2$ and hence $E^2 \sim 1/r^4$. In $n$ dimensional space, $\int_{||x||<\epsilon} ||x||^{-\alpha}d^n x$ blows up when $\alpha>n$.

Comment: I didn't say that. The OP said two point charges, not capacitor. In the case of point charges, the integral does diverge.