# Do Kirchhoff's circuit laws work at relativistic speeds?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-circuits

To a pair of related questions, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687679/what-happens-to-an-rc-circuit-moving-at-relativistic-speeds) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/433230/what-is-the-behavior-of-an-electronic-oscillator-at-relativistic-speeds/434472#434472), regarding the applicability of Kirchhoff's laws in a relativistic regime @Dale rejected the possibility based on the following arguments:

> 1. all lumped elements have no net charge but a current density in one frame is a charge density in another frame, so some components gain net charge
> 2. there is no inductive coupling between lumped elements (a mutual inductance is considered a single lumped element with four terminals)
> 3. the circuit is small enough that c can be ignored and all effects are assumed to happen instantaneously the circuit is small enough that
>    c can be ignored and all effects are assumed to happen instantaneously

And then he states that "*Only with all three of these assumptions can circuit theory be derived from Maxwell’s equations. So without them any attempt to use circuit theory will inevitably lead to contradictions.*"

But I am skeptical of all three.

First #3. It is routine EE practice to add transmission line models if the network gets too large and its connections too long, and transmission line theory is nothing but Kirchhoff's laws over an infinite ladder. If you do not like "infinite" number L-s and C-s then model the delay by a finite set of lumped element circuits, such as in a Thomson-Bessel filters, etc.

Regarding #2 either there is inductive coupling between geometrically separated lumped elements or there is not. If there is such a coupling then, as a first approximation, it can be modeled by an ideal four-terminal inductive transformer. If that is not good enough an approximation, one can make it more complicated by adding more inductive transformers and/or capacitors. Again this does not limit the applicability of Kirchhoff's laws.

Finally #1. I do not understand how/where in Kirchhoff's laws would need that be excluded? If I place a bunch of electrons and freeze them in a dielectric between two plates of a capacitor why would that preempt me to model it as a *capacitor* in the network? If instead dynamically we get bunching but now equally as many positive as negative charges accumulate then if they are close enough to interact then it is a *capacitor* to Kirchhoff's and we have to include that capacitive coupling as it is routinely done on RF boards by engineers fighting the "strays". If they are separated so their interaction is negligible then it is negligible and just does not matter.

All of Maxwell's equations can be translated to Kirchhoff's KCL/KVL equations appropriately modified to include the transmission line models (see Schelkunoff, Dicke, Purcell, etc.) Whether it is practical to do so in any given problem is a separate question but for the simplest and most common distributed systems it is the most practical way, and this includes almost all waveguide circuits, antennas and their matching circuits, etc. Even most antennas can be analyzed this way and it is essentially the only way to find how they behave as a load to a driver or a source to a receiver.

To my surprise I could not find any relevant literature besides discussing such simpler cases as how a capacitance might change with velocity.  So here I am asking for a revisit of these issues:

1. Is @Dale right when he rejects Kirchhoff's laws in the relativistic domain based on his three requirements? Do Kirchhoff's laws really need those assumptions?
2. Is it possible to reformulate KCL/KVL in a relativistic language despite relativistic kinematics' dependence on *geometry* while Kirchhoff's laws are dependent on *topology*? Is it enough to add transmission line models to move from topology to geometry?

Comment: All of @Dale's points apply to real circuits in the lab, but Kirchhoff's laws are useful anyway. Real components carry charge, real currents couple through induction, and real networks have delays. In practice, you add extra components as needed to account for these effects where they are significant.

Comment: Kirchhoff's laws don't even work at non-relativistic speeds when (slowly) changing electric and magnetic fields are present ("hum"). It's called EMI and it takes some serious engineering effort to deal with it properly. So, yeah, it's one of those highly useful but ultimately incomplete approximations.

Comment: @FlatterMann They work if you put in enough "parasitic" components. But it gets tedious, and isn't terribly illuminating.

Comment: @JohnDoty A parasitic component merely means that we admit defeat in the face of the task of having to solve Maxwell's equations. We aren't putting them in because we want to or because they are so great. We are putting them in because solving the actual problem is just too darn hard and they are a quick workaround that makes us feel good.

Comment: @FlatterMann They get the job done. All calculation in  physics is of this nature: at some point the reductionist approach becomes impractical/impossible. Still, we often find models that work.

Comment: @JohnDoty That's what I am saying. Kirchhoff is a useful approximation and that is all it is and ever will be. We do, of course, not care about calculating the last 1e-12W of far field emissions from a well designed 100kHz power supply. Maxwell can do that, but nobody needs it.

Comment: @FlatterMann Every model in physics is a useful approximation, and will never be more.

Answer (score 3):

> To my surprise I could not find any relevant literature

I think that this is important to keep in mind. I also do not know of any literature describing a complete relativistic circuit theory. So my base assumption is that it is not possible, simply from the literature.

While I have specific arguments for some of @hyportnex’s objections, I do not have them for all. But I assume the missing arguments do not affect the outcome. Otherwise some clever theoretician in the last century would have developed a relativistic circuit theory.

> Is it possible to reformulate KCL/KVL in a relativistic language despite relativistic kinematics' dependence on geometry while Kirchhoff's laws are dependent on topology?

This is, I think, the biggest issue. Relativity is a geometrical theory and circuit theory is topological. How could velocity even be introduced to a topological theory? Would a theory still deserve the name of “circuit theory” if you have to identify the path of each wire and the position of each circuit element?

Frankly, I think not, so I think relativistic circuit theory is a self contradiction from the beginning. If a theory requires the specification of the geometry, then I would not call it circuit theory. And I don’t see how a theory can be relativistic without the geometry.

I think this objection is not fixable. In any case, it is strong enough for me to require an actual working relativistic circuit theory as the counter proof. While the absence of such a working theory in the scientific literature is not a proof of its impossibility, it is certainly strong supporting evidence.

> Do Kirchhoff's laws really need those assumptions?

Circuit theory textbooks state then quite clearly, so I would be hesitant to dismiss any of them. But let’s examine the impact of each assumption.

> all lumped elements have no net charge …
>
> I do not understand how/where in Kirchhoff's laws would need that be excluded?

This is the one for which I do not have a complete answer. If the total charge on any circuit element varies then Kirchoff’s current law (KCL) is violated as the current leaving the element is not the same as the current entering it.

So it is clear that the net charge on each element must be constant. While requiring it to be zero does imply that it is constant, zero is obviously not the only constant. So I cannot argue that it needs to be zero, merely that it needs to be constant.

The fact that the textbooks state it as zero and not just constant makes me suspect that I am missing some argument. But let’s investigate both the zero-charge and the constant-charge assumptions.

Now, in relativity a current density in one frame is a charge density and a current density in other frames. So the zero-charge assumption excludes relativistic inertial circuits. The constant-charge assumption would not exclude relativistic inertial circuits, but it would exclude relativistic accelerating circuits. KCL would fail as the accelerating circuit elements accumulate net charge.

> there is no inductive coupling between lumped elements …
>
> If there is such a coupling then, as a first approximation, it can be modeled by an ideal four-terminal inductive transformer.

Violation of this assumption makes it so that the voltages around a loop no longer sun to zero. This directly violates Kirchoff’s voltage law (KVL).

Your proposed approach for addressing such violations is clever, but you are probably overly optimistic about how it would work. First, you may need many more than four terminals in general. Second, and more importantly, in general you will not be able to treat the resulting multi-terminal element as a transformer.

To determine the current voltage relationship for this element will require a derivation or some good experiments. Such a derivation, in turn, could not use circuit theory (KVL is violated), but would typically require Maxwell’s equations. So what would be the point?

> the circuit is small enough that c can be ignored and all effects are assumed to happen instantaneously …
>
> It is routine EE practice to add transmission line models if the network gets too large and its connections too long, and transmission line theory is nothing but Kirchhoff's laws over an infinite ladder

This assumption is necessary for the electro quasi static and magneto quasi static approximations of Maxwell’s equations from which KVL and KCL are derived. In other words, the previous two assumptions are necessary for deriving KVL and KCL, but not sufficient.

While it is true that transmission line models are used by EE’s, so are Maxwell’s equations. The mere use of a technique by EE’s does not make that technique part of circuit theory. Transmission line models are somewhat of a bridge between circuit theory and the full Maxwell’s equations. But in themselves they do violate Kirchoff’s laws, so they are not part of circuit theory.

Transmission line theory has different assumptions than circuit theory: the small cross section assumption and the no mutual interference assumption. Additional assumptions can allow the use of circuit theory, but it is simply untrue that all transmission line models are part of circuit theory.

Obviously, this assumption in itself is not compatible with relativity. So since it is required for both KVL and KCL it is clear that a relativistic circuit theory could not be based on KCL and KVL. It is unclear what relativistic laws could replace them, and even less clear if the resulting theory would merit the label “circuit theory”.

So, in summary, I am not confident about the reason for the zero-charge assumption, but the weaker constant-charge assumption is required for KCL. The no-coupling assumption is required for KVL. The instantaneous assumption is required for both KVL and KCL. However, the strongest argument is the topological vs geometrical issue.

Comment: (1) You always need more than four terminals to be perfect in general. (2) For real circuits, layout matters. You typically attempt to minimize the influence of geometry, but you generally can't get rid of it completely, so you add "parasitics" to your model. (3) Transmission lines are part of the theory, so geometry comes in. Schelkunoff theory is effective for antennas, where geometry dominates. (4) The state of Kirchhoff theory is, in practice, heavily informed by practical applications. Why would anybody waste time extending these approximations in a useless, untestable way?

Comment: I love the geometry/topology contrast. Nicely said.

Comment: @JohnDoty Adding parasitic components is an ad-hoc procedure. It's a poor man's guess of what matters and by how much. There are software tools that can extract the correct parasitic components from geometry, but they are based on proper numerical approximations of Maxwell's equations, which is a non-trivial thing to do. They also require tons of geometry input, which usually isn't available except to the chip designer and, to lesser extent, the package designer. By the time we hit the board level it's basically every man for himself, right now.

Comment: @FlatterMann As mathematician Reuben Hersh points out, once you're fixing a calculation by adding "small" corrections, there's generally no objective procedure for deciding when to stop. Again, essentially all physical calculations have this problem.

Comment: Thank you for this careful review but take a look at this fig 7.12 or 7.16 pp223-224 [here](https://archive.org/details/principlesofmicr0000mont/page/222/mode/2up) representing a cavity in its complete glory  by lumped elements with Kirchhoff's equation or figs 7.2, all based on Foster's reactance theorem applied to the full wave solutions of Maxwell's equation. Since you would not have problem with a cavity at the end of a waveguide being relativistically represented, why would you have a problem with the same being done with an infinite number of L-s and C-s?

Comment: Why would you assume I “would not have problem with a cavity at the end of a waveguide being relativistically represented”?

Comment: I also take issue with your view that " transmission line models [...]  use of a technique by EE’s does not make that technique part of circuit theory. [...] in themselves they do violate Kirchoff’s laws, so they are not part of circuit theory." On the contrary, the telegrapher's equation is derived from KCL/KVL as it is applied to an infinite ladder.

Comment: what I meant is that the full wave solution of the waveguide & cavity must be covariant coming directly from Maxwell's equations just as a free space propagating wave would be; and if I use KCL/KVL to represent the same solution exactly then the result of that should also be covariant.

Comment: @JohnDoty In real life your manager will set the cutoff by asking why you have been spending $3000/pF on circuit simulation optimization. :-)

Comment: and a transmission line *is* geometrical because where there is a *bend* or any other discontinuity you can and must represent it by some added L or C as it is always done for waveguides.

Comment: @hyportnex You can readily test with an RF impedance analyzer that RG-58 cable (which is the most common "transmission line" out there apart from IT communication wiring) is fairly insensitive to reasonable bending in the useful bandwidth range.  It would be a real catastrophe for RF engineers if that wasn't the case. Transmission lines are usually used far away from the TEM modes that you are thinking about right now.

Comment: @FlatterMann I think you have completely misunderstood the intent of both my question and of Dale's answer. I think I can speak for him in this context that neither of us questions whether we can achieve 0.999c speed for a waveguide or a PC board stuffed with 1k resistors and then see what happens. Instead, I am asking whether it is possible to formulate KCL/KVL relativistically, and this is a theoretical question unrelated to RG-58 cables. Dale thinks it cannot be done, and gave three reasons. I think it can be done because I think his reasons are either invalid or

Comment: ... it can be augmented if we are allowed to use ideal transmission lines in the model within the realm of Kirchhoff's equations as applied to an *infinite* homogeneous ladder network representing distributed parameters. These are ideal lines whose behavior changes if they have a kink because the L per unit length and C per unit length might change.

Comment: @hyportnex said “I think it can be done” and yet neither of us can find an example of it having been done. And that is despite more than 100 years of time for someone to have done it. Quibbling over whether or not to include transmission lines doesn’t alter that fact

Comment: Dale, that is a very strong argument in your favor and I do not claim to be smart enough to come up with an answer, that is why I was asking.  But there are equally "simple" questions in classical physics without adequate resolution. Take for example the by now nearly eternal quest to find a working general, preferably variational, principle for a polythermal steady state thermodynamic system, no time dependence, just steady state. Could macroscopic physics be *that* impotent?

Comment: @hyportnex I was simply saying that reasonable limits of the approximation stop at the level of TEM modes in waveguides. The reason why relativity is not even in play is simple: you have a ground node. That's your preferred reference system, if you want.

Comment: @FlatterMann a homogeneous ladder network can just as well represent a TEM mode as a TE or TM modes, or any propagating mode in a waveguide where transverse modes do not even exist, see for example, Borgnis & Papas pp304-5. Also, why would anyone need a "ground node" or reference point for KCL/KVL? A "ground node" is a *practical* design convenience not a theoretical requirement in a circuit; I am at a total loss to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @hyportnex Yes, it can and it's maximally inefficient in doing that. At best it's a crutch, at worst it's an admission that one did not care reading a book about numerical algorithms for the solutions to Maxwell's equations. In no case does the approximation represent an actual geometry. The spectrum is always wrong, no matter how fine we make the grids. It also does not solve the relativity problem because the finite number of degrees of freedom inside the simulated cavity do not eliminate the problems with ground and, worse... the boundary conditions to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

> Do Kirchhoff's laws really need those assumptions?

Not all of those, not really.

KVL is a useful rule for formulation of circuit equations, based on the fact that electric potential is a single-valued function of position in space. This holds in the relativistic scenario as well. Values of potential and of parameters $R,L,C,\mathscr{E}$ of circuit components may have different values in the frame where the circuit moves, and it may be difficult to express them (e.g. due to external induced emfs) but the fact remains valid.

KCL states that for any region of space where there are no components but only perfect conductors connected to their terminals, sum of currents entering the region equals sum of currents leaving the region, or in other words, integral of current density over closed boundary of that region is zero. Mathematically, everywhere outside the components,
$$
\nabla'\cdot \mathbf j' = 0,
$$
which means that in those regions (assuming the Maxwell equations)
$$
\partial_t' \rho' = 0.
$$

This holds in the rest frame of the circuit $S'$. Does it also hold in the frame $S$ where the circuit moves relativistically with velocity $v$?

Unfortunately, not in general. From the Lorentz transformation, we know that a piece of current-carrying perfect conductor with zero charge density in its rest frame ($\rho' = 0$) will have, in general, non-zero charge density $\rho$ proportional to current density $j_x'$ in direction of the velocity. In a DC scenario, where $j_x'$ is constant in time, $\rho$ will be constant in time as well, so $\nabla \cdot \mathbf j = 0$ and KCL holds in $S$. But when currents change in time (AC circuits), $j_x'$ is changing in time, and $\rho$ is no longer constant in time, and thus $\nabla \cdot \mathbf j$ no longer vanishes and thus KCL does not hold.

Nevertheless, all physics variables in both frames seem to be related via linear transformations, so the moving circuit should still be correctly described by some set of linear differential equations. It is just not possible in general to obtain those equations from KVL and KCL applied in the frame where the circuit moves.

Comment: You are basically saying that we can't describe the Doppler shift of an oscillator, right? How do L(v) and C(v) scale? Do they scale differently for transverse and longitudinal Doppler?

Comment: There is no radiation in circuit equations based on KVL and KCL, so I'm not sure what you mean by "Doppler shift of an oscillator".

Comment: Current includes displacement current.

Comment: @JohnDoty which current? Not the currents in lumped element circuits.

Comment: What I mean is that a circuit description usually has a ground node. The Doppler shift calculation would require two ground nodes that move relative to each other. I can, of course, put the equations into modern circuit simulators that can evaluate any arbitrary function, including an arbitrary function of time, but that ain't what Kirchhoff had in mind.

Comment: I think John Doty means that an AC current through a capacitor is a displacement current. I think he is right about that... what Maxwell describes, though, and what the theory requires, is current densities in free space. The nodes, in this case, become more or less arbitrary surfaces and we have to start simulating Maxwell's equations with cells that have volume and surface elements. Can be done, of course... right until we hit motion. How does a moving antenna fit into such a framework? Now we have to make time dependent circuit elements that "connect" to different cells at different times?

Comment: I was thinking more of a CCD. If you're moving charge packets around, you don't have zero divergence of current unless you account for displacement.

Comment: In general, Kirchhoff will bite you if you don't pay attention to accounting for all significant displacement current and induction.

Comment: @Flattermann I don't think my answer has anything to do with ground nodes or Doppler shifts. You can denote any node of an RLC circuit as the ground node. It does not change anything in behaviour of the circuit.

Comment: @JánLalinský The physical equivalent of a ground node is global. It assumes that we can pick up the difference between the ground potential and any other node instantaneously. This clashes with relativity immediately. It also makes it hard to define "motion" in a relative way in such a circuit description. At best we could set up time dependent delay lines and measure the differences between them, but even that violates relativity as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JohnDoty If we take displacement current as valid part of total current, then total current density is always divergenceless, and KCL is always trivially valid. But such current exists around the conductors in isolators and this is not how circuits are usually described. Lumped element model works only with conduction current.

Comment: @Flattermann I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: If the lumped element model was so restricted, it would be crippled. But "parasitic" capacitors save the day.

Comment: Why do you suppose that capacitors are sometimes drawn with a curved plate in schematics? What does that signify?

Comment: @JánLalinský I am talking about the same thing that Dale mentioned in his answer: nodes are topology. Real wires and ground planes are geometry.

Comment: @JohnDoty that the capacitor there has defined polarity, e.g. an electrolytic capacitor. This has nothing to do whatsoever with the question.

Comment: @JánLalinský Wrong. If the cap is polar, it should have a + sign on one of the plates. The curved plate signifies the plate more exposed to the environment: the outer foil of a tubular, the lower plate of an IC cap, etc. Why do you suppose that's important?

Comment: @JohnDoty Ok, I may have read wrong source on that. It is not usual to use such symbols in Europe. What is your source on that claim? Still, you should explain yourself, instead of me guessing and answering your questions here.

Comment: @JánLalinský See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670249/why-is-there-a-polarized-capacitor-symbol-in-an-ac-circuit

Answer (score 0):

The essential issue here is that we must draw a distinction between the textbook cartoon version of Kirchhoff's laws and the real world version. In reality, we patch up the cartoon as needed to account for time delay, displacement current, and induction. Yes, the cartoon won't work at relativistic speed, but it doesn't even work on the bench. If you use Kirchhoff's laws, you are implicitly promising to account for effects beyond the cartoon as required in practice.

Comment: > *it doesn't even work on the bench* You're right that the idealized formulation does not take into account distributed parameters, and parameters are always distributed.  But is still does work in practical sense (not with absolute accuracy, but with reasonably good accuracy) for DC circuits, and simple linear AC circuits in low enough frequency regime.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer to my question and it is too long for a comment but it is a start.

---

In this excellent [note](http://web.hep.uiuc.edu/home/serrede/p436/lecture_notes/p436_lect_18p5.pdf), Prof. Errede derives two results as to how the fields of a capacitor and of a coil transform from one inertial system to another. First I just summarize a few relevant results described there.
For the capacitor:
[image: capacitor in the stationary frame]

$$\vec{E}=\gamma_0 E_0\hat y \tag{1e}$$
$$\vec{B}=-\frac{\gamma_0}{c}\beta_0 E_0\hat z \tag{1b}$$

Here $E_0=\frac{V}{d_0}$ is the homogeneous field intensity between plates separated by $d_0$ and voltage drop $V$.

For the coil:
[image: coil in the stationary frame]
$$\vec{E}=0 \tag{2e}$$
$$\vec{B}=\mu_0 \mathcal {N} I \hat x \tag{2b}$$
where $\mathcal {N}$ is the number of turns per unit length.

For quasi-stationary approximation to hold, one that ignores all radiation effects, we must assume that ideally lumped circuits are point-like. In practice this means that their characteristic length must not be larger than a few percent of the free-space wavelength.

Errede's notes do not discuss the field transformation of the coil for lateral motion, but that is addressed for a single loop in Panofsky-Phillips with the result that along the *perimeter* of rectangular loop, 2 long and 2 short sides, carrying a current $I$ there develops a static dipole, so that one side is negatively charged the other is equally positively charged. The charge separation is within the confines the rectangular loop and the charge, and thus the dipole moment is proportional to the current. I have not been able to derive the same for a circular loop let alone for a coil but I am confident that a similar result will come about, just as I am confident that a similar development will happen if the capacitor is not a pair of planar plates but are made of a more complicated structure resulting in a magnetic field orthogonal to both the electric field inside, thus the voltage between the terminals, and to the motion.

[image: Panofsky-Phillips, page 334]

The import of all this is that both the capacitor and the coil stay *lumped* that is all the relativistic effects stay inside the body of the element and the effect is a linear function of the voltage and current, respectively. An engineer modeling this would say that a capacitor is to be augmented in series with a voltage controlled current source that is an inductor; while the coil is to be augmented in parallel with a current controlled voltage source that is a capacitor. All this modification is completely *within* the classical lumped element version of Kirchhoff's KCL and KVL.

All this must include the proviso that the free space wavelength be much larger than any of the circuit elements. Here the motion towards the observer must be taken into account because the Doppler effect shrinks the wavelength already unrelated to relativity. That is we have a limit as to how fast we can move *towards* the observer and still maintain quasi-stationarity.

Geometry comes into play by noticing that the relativistic effect on each element depends on said point-like element's disposition relative to the motion. In the stationary system this is completely ignored by the KCL/KVL but it shows up in the controlled sources attached to the elements.

Where KCL/KVL may run into trouble is the *connecting* wires that are completely ignored by them, again as a result of assuming that the whole circuit is essentially point-like, no geometry, only topology. Here I can only offer what in my original question I already alluded to in that its resolution will be accounting for the wires as multi-coupled transmission lines. An example for which one must do something like that already is in the high frequency PC boards where the spurious coupling between connecting *microstrip* transmission lines are to be accounted for. (The fact that these PC boards usually have a common ground plane is incidental to this argument, it makes the system work better but coupled wires do not have to have a common ground plane.)

Of course, once we introduce transmission lines connecting the lumped elements we are not in the realm of the KCL/KVL as usually are formulated. To avoid misunderstanding I use the term *transmission line*, for lack of a better term, in  a more general sense than just having two parallel Lecher wires. To me a transmission line is anything that guides EM waves. And when understood in this sense a transmission line can be represented as an infinite long set of L-s and C-s starting between the terminals of the driver source (no need for a common ground) and extending between the various wires. The said distributed not necessarily homogeneous L-s and C-s can be lumped to a few finite elements and thereby simplify the circuit but they all follow KCL/KVL and I *believe* that their relativistic effects can be handled same as the normal elements.

In summary, I still believe in Kirchhoff!